# WPF - Change button image source when clicks button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to change the image source when a click event has occurred. I can change the image in XAML, but not from code. I've tried getting the Image property from the Button, but that doesn't work.

I am using Caliburn for the event call:

```
<Button Content="Mark1" Height="30" Width="40" 
cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SayHello($source, $this)]">
   <Image Name="Mark1ButtonImage"  Source="image1.png" />
</Button>
```

In C# code:

```
public void SayHello(object sender, object doodlesource)
{
    var selectedButton = sender as Button;
    var selectedKrav = doodlesource as Doodle;
    if (selectedButton != null)
    {
       ///WHAT TO DO TO CHANGE? selectedButton.Image doesn't work?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"foo.png"));

    SelectedBtn.Content=img
```

Answer (score 0):

To find your image Inside your button, you will need to use this line of code :

```
var image = (sender as Button).FindVisualChildren<Image>();
```

Then you can change the source of your image.

Comment: are you sure findvisualchildren exists? visual studio doesn't find it

Comment: what version of .net are you using? I'm using 4.5 and it is there. There should be another function that does the same thing, but with a different name...